# What is Indecent Exposure?

Tags: refactoring

in regards to indecent exposure for code refactoring, what exactly would be a pliable definition? I keep looking online, but cannot find anything concrete or more than a word/two to define it? Also if you could provide me with a code example (in Java)  where you have a case that has Indecent Exposure and a code example of a solution that would be terrific! If you could also give me some pros and cons of Indecent Exposure I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I find this [definition](http://blog.amitinside.com/Principle-of-Indecent-Exposure/):

> Do not expose any array publicly whose compile-time component type in not reifiable.

to be pretty specific; and it comes with code samples, too.